# LIfetime management of Dbcontext using Unity with ThreadPool

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, unity-container, threadpool

I'm currently building an ASP.NET MVC application with Unity and Entity framework. I'm using the Unity MVC 3 setup where it uses the ContainerControlledLifetimeManager to resolve the dependency (http://devtrends.co.uk/blog/introducing-the-unity.mvc3-nuget-package-to-reconcile-mvc3-unity-and-idisposable). This works fine until I try to spin up another thread that executes a time-consuming task after the page is loaded, and the user receives updates. From the thread, I get this error:

`The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.`

I believe it's because the main thread has completed so the container and it's children gets disposed. Does anyone know of a solution for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the code where you are declaring and using DbContext..? perhps you are doing something within a using(){}

Comment: are you injecting a context? code definitely here please : )

Answer (score 3):

The standard context lifetime handling with dependency injection into controller cannot work in your scenario because you want to use injected context after its expected lifetime (controller is already released).

Your time consuming operation must have reference to another unity container and must ask for a new context instance resolved with Transient or PerResolve lifetime manager. When your operation completes or aborts it must handle context disposal.

IMHO spanning custom thread in ASP.NET (or any IIS hosted) application is not very good idea.

Answer (score 0):

More often than not, the problem is that in your Controller you have code like:

```
public ActionResult Blah()
{
  MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel();

  using (var dbc = new MyDbContext())
  {
    model.items = from x in dbc.items select x;
  }    

  View(model)
}
```

`items` has not been resolved in this case, so the solution is:

```
    model.items = (from x in dbc.items select x).ToList();
```

Comment: OP clearly explains that he's using Unity for dependency injection, so there wouldn't be any "new MyDbContext())".